# Deploy WordPress From Local Docker to Hosting Provider

Tags: hosting, git, testing, deployment, docker

I've seen articles that teach [how to migrate WordPress into Docker containers](https://joshmobley.net/writing/2017/04/09/easy-wordpress-migration-with-docker.html) ([see also here](https://stephenafamo.com/blog/moving-wordpress-docker-container/)). I want to do the opposite.  I am already running WordPress locally via Docker on my Windows 10 laptop.  I want to migrate my local (containerized) WordPress instance into a hosted provider (e.g. WP Engine, GoDaddy, Bluehost, etc.).  I don't think these hosting providers offer containerized WordPress hosting, and even if they did - it likely is more expensive than their traditional infrastructure.

I also like the idea of pushing updates (plugin and theme changes or additions) to my hosting provider via git, like I see described in this [WP Engine Git Setup](https://wpengine.com/git/) article.

I'd like advice or instructions for this.  I am passable with my Docker skills, but I am new to WordPress.  The most important things I need to understand:

- How do I preserve articles I've written and published on my hosting provider, when I suddenly "git push" new updates to my hosting provider?
- How do I backup my database on my local computer, given that my containerized WordPress does not have phpMyAdmin included?
- How do I ensure that path names like "http://localhost:8000" that I use for local testing are properly replaced with the proper domain-name when I push?
- Need I be concerned with the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder?  Where is the official documentation for this special folder?  Are there other "magic" directories like this I should be aware of?
- How might [VersionPress](https://versionpress.net/) fit into this story, if at all?
- Is there anything fundamentally flawed about what I am trying to achieve?

Ultimately I don't need a "git push" deployment model.  For example, I doubt GoDaddy or Bluehost will offer me the "git push" capability, but their hosting is also less expensive; I could accept an FTP deploy if it was not too burdensom.  But whether I deploy with git or deploy with FTP, I still want the  ability to run my development effort within Docker, and version locally with git.

Also, I am not actually developing brand new WordPress themes or plugins.  I am simply using my local WordPress container to add and test pre-existing themes and plugins.

### Background

I am using the docker-compose file shown below.  It will only work if you change "Docker for Windows" Settings->Shared Drives...so that a Windows drive (the "C" drive in my case) is shared.  Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: wp_db
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    wp_db:
      driver_opts:
        type: none
        device: ./wp-db
        o: bind
```

The above allows (I think) all of the WordPress themes and plugins (along with DB modifications) to be exposed on my file system, outside of the WordPress container.  I can then capture these files into git.  My plan is to use the [WordPress `.gitignore` file suggested by Github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/WordPress.gitignore), or perhaps one of the `.gitignore` files described in the aforementioned WP Engine article.

Comment: VersionPress.com (note the ".com") is a containerized platform, based on Docker. We don't have a Git deployment method yet but it's something we plan to do and will handle things like URL rewriting for you automatically.